# Radio buttons used in a rad grid in batch edit mode

Tags: radio-button, telerik, radgrid

I am trying to find any information about using a radio button in a rad grid in batch edit mode.  I have created a template column, then added the radio button control, but it doesn't work in batch edit mode (nothing saves back to the DB).  Is it even possible?  I can't find anything on the Telerik site so I am suspecting its not supported.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Radio list is not supported in the batch editing mode. Such integration simply has not been implemented. The closest available option at this time is using a dropdown list: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/batch-editing/defaultcs.aspx. Generally speaking, the standard way of editing boolean fields is through a checkbox column and not a radio button list - check the Discontinued checkboxes column.

What the grid does is that it loops through the controls with JS code when cells are opened and closed and determines control types and the proper API to use (e.g., $get().control.get_value() for dropdownlists, or $get().value for standard inputs). You can try implementing similar logic in the batch editing events.

You can try to use a RadRadioButtonList with the two items declared in its markup and its client-side API (see the get_selectedIndex() and set_selectedIndex() method: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/radiobuttonlist/client-side-programming/radiobuttonlist-object) together with the following approach of working with templates: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/edit-mode/batch-editing/working-with-templates.
The idea is to have the radio button list in the edit template of the column and to select the correct item in it according to the newly opened cell value on the client, then fetch the selected item from the button list and put it in the grid data source.
You can find one example that you can try using as base in the following thread: https://www.telerik.com/forums/radiobuttonlist-in-gridtemplatecolumn.

Showing a radio button list in the item template is also something that is not supported, as the editing would basically happen in the "display" mode of the cell, and not in the edit mode of the cell. You could try using the server ItemDataBound event and FindControl() (see here: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/rows/accessing-cells-and-rows#accessing-controls-in-template-column) may let you set initial values based on the data source for the radio button lists without data binding them. Then, perhaps a hidden field or hidden checkbox can be used for the actual data binding (see the template article above). You could also try using the batch editing manager changeCellValue() method on the client-side events of the radio button list, in a fashion similar to this article: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/edit-mode/batch-editing/how-to/editing-checkboxes.

Another approach you can consider is to use the client-side events of the radio button list and immediately upon change to call a service that will update the database. This may simplify the template handling logic (you could do this in a read-only column) but it goes against the purpose of batch editing to invoke one request with a lot of data, and you would also need to secure the service.

Another online resource to check is
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/edit-mode/batch-editing/how-to/editing-checkboxes

Comment: Wow that is amazing!, Thanks for the help, I am going to work my way through this and see if I can make one of these ideas work.